# Charting a Rolling Information Ratio

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

Using the performance analytics package in r, i note there is a way to plot the rolling performance or sharpe ratios for time series data. I would like anyone to describe how you can calculate the rolling information ratio?

This is the command line for rolling sharp ratio - tried this by replacing FUN= 'InformationRatio.Annualized' but that didn't work? any ideas

```
chart.RollingPerformance(strategies[, c(1,2,3)], FUN =
'SharpeRatio.annualized', width = 12, colorset = tim6equal, lwd = 2,
legend.loc="topleft",cex.axis=1, cex.legend=0.4, main = "Rolling
12-Month Sharpe Ratio strategies")
```

Comment: Some reproducible example data and a desired outcome would be helpful.

Comment: You can not use the 'chart.RollingPerformance' as for the calculation of the Information Ratio 2 return series are necessary ( asset returns AND benchmark returns ). See help: "any function that can be evaluated using a single set of returns".